# Inconsistent problems with Google Sheets data mover script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

After around two to three hours of digging across many sites, I cobbled together this functioning script to watch an "input" column on a sheet and, using onEdit(), whenever data is put into that column, move the data further down the sheet to the next available cell in that specific row.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = 'Pricing Chart';
  var colToWatch = 5;
  var copyFrom = 5;
  var nextEmptyCol = colToWatch + 22;
  var emptyCellCheck = s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, nextEmptyCol,1,1);
  
  if (s.getName() !== sheetName || e.range.columnStart !== colToWatch) return;
  
  while (emptyCellCheck.isBlank() !== true){
    nextEmptyCol++;
    var emptyCellCheck = s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, nextEmptyCol,1,1);
  }
  
  if (emptyCellCheck.isBlank()){
    s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, copyFrom,1,1)
    .copyTo(s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, nextEmptyCol,1,1), {contentsOnly: true}),
      s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, copyFrom,1,1).clear({contentsOnly: true});
  } 
}
```

Specific example:

Into cell E5, type "222". If AA5 is empty, it will copy "222" into AA5, and then clear E5. If AA5 is not empty, it will check AB5, then AC5, etc until it finds an empty cell. On my specific sheet, it then uses all the data from the row and displays various calculations (average, max, etc) so that those data are visible, but all the individual inputs are tucked away behind the scenes. It's been useful for keeping a large list of data on many different variables in a format that's easy to look at and easy to share with others.

Problem is... sometimes it will do as intended at first, find the next available cell, copy the data, and erase the original input cell (e.g. E5). But, sometimes, it will also erase the cell the data was copied TO (e.g. AB5). Roughly once or twice every ten iterations of the script.

So, I was wondering if anyone could have a look at my script and give me tips on optimizing it or just doing things better so the script runs correctly consistently.

Comment: Can you provide a sample spreadsheet for reproducing your situation? I think that it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: [This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TB-FZO97FaW_m_-26v-mQIfvRech5lwr5Ta9eUpeKNk/edit?usp=sharing) is the sheet I use it on.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, in my environment, I couldn't replicate your situation. Can you provide the way to replicate your situation?

Comment: Thanks for trying to replicate it! Unfortunately, there's no other information I can give. I use that exact script on the spreadsheet I linked and sometimes it deletes the information in the cell it copies to in addition to the cell being copied from. Very strange. Is it possible that the script is seeing its own clear as a separate onEdit() trigger, making it run twice?

Comment: Although, I suppose if that were the case, it would never stop looping.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although this is my guess, for example, how about using [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/)? By this, the exclusion operation of the script can be done. I'm not sure whether this is useful for your situation. So If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.